# Runge-Kutta 4 With CUDA Fortran

Tags: cuda, fortran, fortran90

I am trying to convert this FORTRAN program (motion of pendulum) to CUDA FORTRAN but I can use only 1 block with two threads. Is there any way to use more then 2 threads....

```
MODULE CB
    REAL :: Q,B,W
END MODULE CB

PROGRAM PENDULUM
    USE CB
    IMPLICIT NONE
    INTEGER, PARAMETER :: N=10,L=100,M=1
    INTEGER :: I,count_rate,count_max,count(2)
    REAL :: PI,H,T,Y1,Y2,G1,G1F,G2,G2F
    REAL :: DK11,DK21,DK12,DK22,DK13,DK23,DK14,DK24

    REAL, DIMENSION (2,N) :: Y

    PI = 4.0*ATAN(1.0)
    H  = 3.0*PI/L
    Q  = 0.5
    B  = 0.9
    W  = 2.0/3.0
    Y(1,1) = 0.0
    Y(2,1) = 2.0

    DO I = 1, N-1
        T  = H*I
        Y1 = Y(1,I)
        Y2 = Y(2,I)
        DK11 = H*G1F(Y1,Y2,T)
        DK21 = H*G2F(Y1,Y2,T)
        DK12 = H*G1F((Y1+DK11/2.0),(Y2+DK21/2.0),(T+H/2.0))
        DK22 = H*G2F((Y1+DK11/2.0),(Y2+DK21/2.0),(T+H/2.0))
        DK13 = H*G1F((Y1+DK12/2.0),(Y2+DK22/2.0),(T+H/2.0))
        DK23 = H*G2F((Y1+DK12/2.0),(Y2+DK22/2.0),(T+H/2.0))
        DK14 = H*G1F((Y1+DK13),(Y2+DK23),(T+H))
        DK24 = H*G2F((Y1+DK13),(Y2+DK23),(T+H))
        Y(1,I+1) = Y(1,I)+(DK11+2.0*(DK12+DK13)+DK14)/6.0
        Y(2,I+1) = Y(2,I)+(DK21+2.0*(DK22+DK23)+DK24)/6.0

        ! Bring theta back to the region [-pi,pi]
        Y(1,I+1) = Y(1,I+1)-2.0*PI*NINT(Y(1,I+1)/(2.0*PI))

    END DO

    call system_clock ( count(2), count_rate, count_max )

    WRITE (6,"(2F16.8)") (Y(1,I),Y(2,I),I=1,N,M)

END PROGRAM PENDULUM

FUNCTION G1F (Y1,Y2,T) RESULT (G1)
    USE CB
    IMPLICIT NONE
    REAL :: Y1,Y2,T,G1
    G1 = Y2
END FUNCTION G1F

FUNCTION G2F (Y1,Y2,T) RESULT (G2)
    USE CB
    IMPLICIT NONE
    REAL :: Y1,Y2,T,G2
    G2 = -Q*Y2-SIN(Y1)+B*COS(W*T)
END FUNCTION G2F
```

---

CUDA FORTRAN VERSION OF PROGRAM

---

```
MODULE KERNEL

    CONTAINS  
    attributes(global) subroutine mykernel(Y_d,N,L,M)

    INTEGER,value:: N,L,M
    INTEGER ::tid
    REAL:: Y_d(:,:)
    REAL :: PI,H,T,G1,G1F,G2,G2F
    REAL,shared :: DK11,DK21,DK12,DK22,DK13,DK23,DK14,DK24,Y1,Y2

    PI = 4.0*ATAN(1.0)
    H  = 3.0*PI/L
    Y_d(1,1) = 0.0
    Y_d(2,1) = 2.0
    tid=threadidx%x

    DO I = 1, N-1
        T  = H*I
        Y1 = Y_d(1,I)
        Y2 = Y_d(2,I)

        if(tid==1)then
            DK11 = H*G1F(Y1,Y2,T)
        else
            DK21 = H*G2F(Y1,Y2,T)
        endif

        call syncthreads ()

        if(tid==1)then
            DK12 = H*G1F((Y1+DK11/2.0),(Y2+DK21/2.0),(T+H/2.0))
        else
            DK22 = H*G2F((Y1+DK11/2.0),(Y2+DK21/2.0),(T+H/2.0))
        endif

        call syncthreads ()

        if(tid==1)then
            DK13 = H*G1F((Y1+DK12/2.0),(Y2+DK22/2.0),(T+H/2.0))
        else
            DK23 = H*G2F((Y1+DK12/2.0),(Y2+DK22/2.0),(T+H/2.0))
        endif

        call syncthreads ()

        if(tid==1)then
            DK14 = H*G1F((Y1+DK13),(Y2+DK23),(T+H))
        else
            DK24 = H*G2F((Y1+DK13),(Y2+DK23),(T+H))
        endif

        call syncthreads ()

        if(tid==1)then
            Y_d(1,I+1) = Y1+(DK11+2.0*(DK12+DK13)+DK14)/6.0
        else
            Y_d(2,I+1) = Y2+(DK21+2.0*(DK22+DK23)+DK24)/6.0
        endif

        Y_d(1,I+1) = Y_d(1,I+1)-2.0*PI*NINT(Y_d(1,I+1)/(2.0*PI))

        call syncthreads ()

    END DO

end subroutine mykernel

attributes(device) FUNCTION G1F (Y1,Y2,T) RESULT (G1)
    IMPLICIT NONE
    REAL :: Y1,Y2,T,G1
    G1 = Y2
END FUNCTION G1F

attributes(device) FUNCTION G2F (Y1,Y2,T) RESULT (G2)
    IMPLICIT NONE
    REAL :: Y1,Y2,T,G2
    G2 = -0.5*Y2-SIN(Y1)+0.9*COS((2.0/3.0)*T)
END FUNCTION G2F

END MODULE KERNEL

PROGRAM PENDULUM

    use cudafor
    use KERNEL

    IMPLICIT NONE
    INTEGER, PARAMETER :: N=100000,L=1000,M=1
    INTEGER :: I,d,count_max,count_rate

    REAL,device :: Y_d(2,N)
    REAL, DIMENSION (2,N) :: Y
    INTEGER :: count(2)

    call mykernel<<<1,2>>>(Y_d,N,L,M)

    Y=Y_d

    WRITE (6,"(2F16.8)") (Y(1,I),Y(2,I),I=1,N,M)

END PROGRAM PENDULUM
```

Comment: Unless `g1f` and `g2f` are computationally expensive functions which can be evaluated using parallelism (such as a matrix-vector product), or unless you are planning on applying the Runge-Kutta integrator to many systems in parallel (such as in a particle system), this question is an exercise in futility.

Comment: @VladimirF: The point is you can't get rid of the loop. This is an ODE integrator - the values at one trip through the loop dependent on the results of the calculation from the previous trip through the loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can see that only two independent threads of execution are possible by doing a data-dependency analysis of your original serial code.  It's easiest to think of this as an "outer" and an "inner" part.

The "outer" part is the dependence of `Y(1:2,i+1)` on `Y(1:2,i)`.  At each time step, you need to use the values of `Y(1:2,i)` to calculate `Y(1:2,i+1)`, so it's not possible to perform the calculations for multiple time steps in parallel, simply because of the serial dependence structure -- you need to know what happens at time `i` to calculate what happens at time `i+1`, you need to know what happens at time `i+1` to calculate what happens at time `i+2`, and so on.  The best that you can hope to do is to calculate `Y(1,i+1)` and `Y(2,i+1)` in parallel, which is exactly what you do.

The "inner" part is based on the dependencies between the intermediate values in the Runge-Kutta scheme, the `DK11`, `DK12`, etc. values in your code.  When calculating `Y(1:2,i+1)`, each of the `DK[n,m]` depends on `Y(1:2,i)` and for `m > 1`, each of the `DK[n,m]` depends on both `DK[1,m-1]` and `DK[2,m-1]`.  If you draw a graph of these dependencies (which my ASCII art skills aren't really good enough for!), you'll see that there are at each step of the calculation only two possible sub-calculations that can be performed in parallel.

The result of all this is that you cannot do better than two parallel threads for this calculation.  As one of the commenters above said, you can certainly do much better if you're simulating a particle system or some other mechanical system with multiple independent degrees of freedom, which you can then integrate in parallel.